# Split and extract data from a field php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this data saved in a MySQL row:

```
34:3,37:2,64:1,85:4
```

The first number is an ID that identifies a user, the second number (separated by ":") is the arrival order position.

I need to extract and split the data to create a table with the arrivals order:

Something similar to:

```
name position
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: explode()

explode(",", $yourdata);

[PHP Explode](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$split = explode(';', $myvars);
$id = $split[0];
$whatever = $split[1];
```